# Sizers... - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, boxsizer

Ok, so I'm learning about sizers in wxPython and I was wondering if it was possible to do something like:

```
==============================================
|WINDOW TITLE                          _ [] X|
|============================================|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxNOTEBOOKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|
|________                         ___________|
|IMAGE   |                       |LoginForm  |
|________|                       |___________|
==============================================
```

NOTE:Yeah, I literally got this from [wxPython - picking the right sizer to use in an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892110/wxpython-picking-the-right-sizer-to-use-in-an-application)

With NOTEBOOK expanded to left and bottom, IMAGE to align to left and bottom and loginform align to right and bottom and I managed to do almost everything but now I have a problem..

The problem is that I can't align Loginform and Image separately (im using Box Sizers), and I would like to.

**EDIT:** So everyone can see what I mean:
"Oh and what I was referring to, was basically that if I changed the align, it would affect both LoginForm and Image.. For example if I set the align to RIGHT, both image and loginform would have been aligned to the right because of: sizer.Add(sizer4,0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10). Hope you guys can understand this time"

This is the code I'm using that is causing the problem at the moment, any help is appreciated.
NOTE:The code might be (HUGELY) sloppy as I'm still learning box sizers.
Heres a test code:

```
import wx
class Sizerframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'sizertestframe',size=(790, 524))
        p = wx.Panel(self)
        nb = wx.Notebook(p, size = (750, 332))
        button = wx.Button(p, -1, "loginform1rest", size=(94,23))
        button1 = wx.Button(p, -1, "Login", size=(94,23))
        button2 = wx.Button(p, -1, "Cancel", size=(94,23))
        imagebutton = wx.Button(p, -1, "imagebutton", size=(94,23))



        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer1.Add(nb,1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(sizer1,1, wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.EXPAND, 10)
        sizer.Add((-1, 25))
        sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer2.Add(button, 0)
        sizer3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer3.Add(button1, 0)
        sizer3.Add(button2,0, wx.LEFT, 5)
        sizer2.Add(sizer3, 0)

        sizer4 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer4.Add(imagebutton, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.BOTTOM)
        sizer4.Add(sizer2,0, wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM , 5)
        sizer.Add(sizer4,0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Sizerframe()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: wxGlade. Learn it, live it, love it. It's not perfect, but it's much better than hand-coding it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, although I would still like to know if it was possible to solve my problem :).

Comment: @Francisco – Could you post full code for a minimal but working example?  Please, just as simple as possible, so no images, login boxes, etc, but just use buttons or panels.  There are probably better examples, but I'm hoping for something like what I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546979/2549783#2549783

Comment: @Francisco Aleixo, put a small code which we can run and experiment with, then it would be easy to put a solution

Comment: OK, but now your code and picture don't match because you've added in extra buttons.  If it would get at your point, I suggest removing the extra buttons rather than adding them into the picture.  Currently your example code has sizers nested fairly deeply, so it's difficult to guess what you're going for.

Comment: @Francisco Aleixo, ok code is there but will you tell again , what is the problem? you said "The problem is that I can't align Loginform and Image separately (im using Box Sizers), and I would like to." which doesn't explain much

Comment: Will quote from the answer below:
"Oh and what I was referring to, was basically that if I changed the align, it would affect both LoginForm and Image.. For example if I set the align to RIGHT, both image and loginform would have been aligned to the right because of: sizer.Add(sizer4,0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10). Hope you guys can understand this time."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
container = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
container.Add(self.nb, 1, wx.EXPAND)

login = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
login.Add(self.userLabel)
login.Add(self.userText)

# ... clip, rest of login form additions here

bottom = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
bottom.Add(image)
bottom.Add((0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND)
bottom.Add(login)

container.Add(bottom, 1, wx.EXPAND)
```

Basically, the `bottom.Add((0, 0), 1, wx.EXPAND)` will act as a spacer that'll take up all the space between the image and the login form.  I didn't really understand what you meant by "The problem is that I can't align Loginform and Image separately (im using Box Sizers), and I would like to".  I mostly just followed the illustration in trying to create a layout. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, ill analyze it tomorrow as I'm off to bed, I also added a test code in case you want mess with it, thanks alot for your response nonetheless

Comment: No problem.  You can make most layouts with different combinations of nested BoxSizers.

Comment: Oh and what I was referring to, was basically that if I changed the align, it would affect both LoginForm and Image.. For example if I set the align to RIGHT, both image and loginform would have been aligned to the right because of:
sizer.Add(sizer4,0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.RIGHT, 10).
Hope you can understand this time.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you shouldn't have to worry about that with the "spacer" I added there.

Comment: Instead of that manually-built spacer, you should consider using `bottom.AddStretchSpacer()`.

Comment: Hah, awesome.  How did I miss that one?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry if I'm being ignorant at the moment and I should change something, but at the moment, with that piece of code, again, everything works right but now I can't align (loginform isn't aligned) to right/bottom as I pretended to, instead its only aligned to bottom. Sorry if I'm missing something but I'm still learning and I really want to get this right ;). Still, you helped alot in understanding this, thanks.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?  I guess I still don't understand what you mean by aligned.  Aligned to what?

Comment: http://img121.imageshack.us/i/problemtv.jpg/
Sorry if this isn't the way to post links here in SO.
NOTE: The login form was in the corner with the default size, but in that pic, the form is resized

Comment: Hrmm, I almost want you to post your code again.  That `bottom.AddStretchSpacer()` should take up all the space between the image on the left and the login form on the right.

Comment: I've been searching how the "AddStretchSpacer" works but didn't find anything relevant (or didn't search properly). Adding only bottom.AddStretchSpacer() doesn't do anything so I was wondering how does it work?

Comment: It just adds an empty space that expands.  So, if you only add it, and no controls after it, you won't see anything.

Comment: But just by adding AddStretchSpacer() without any control it adds an empty space that expands? Because it didn't do anything to me, didn't even add a space nor expanded.

Comment: Pastebin your code at pastie.org, or edit your post and paste it

Comment: Yeah, change: `bottom.Add(login,  wx.LEFT, 15)` to `bottom.Add(login)`, or `bottom.Add(login, border=15)` if you still want that border.

Comment: Just did that, and still the same, can't align that loginform to the corner.. And still the AddStretchSpacer() doesn't do any space at all, atleast that I can see of... The only way I see I can do a space  is with your way in your original answer.

Comment: Oh, and change `container.Add(bottom)` to `container.Add(bottom, 1, ex.EXPAND)` - sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much you just solved the problem!
By the way, when I did that it just added a big space at the bottom, do you know the reason? Thank you again!
http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/7240/giantm.jpg

Comment: Whoops, try this: `container.Add(bottom, 0, wx.EXPAND)`

Answer (score 0):

Just tagging on here, I've always found it's easier to make a skeleton of code in [wxFormBuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) and then add the code to your project, as opposed to trial-and-error in pure Python.